# How to set up Application Health & Diagnostics to work?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I've installed AI, included in project (VS2013 Update4), but some of the metrics (app heath & diagnostics) are not working.

If i click "Learn how to", the help is always the same... I folowed all the steps, that must be done, but it doesn't work.

What else do I need to do, to get all of the metrics work?

see attached image:

http://i57.tinypic.com/nv75sz.png

thx
peter

Comment: Can you be more explicit about how you installed? Stating "I did everything but it doesn't work" is not enough detail for anyone to help you.

Comment: Just forgot to tell, that it's a AI point for deployed Azure web site, so, as I've just now seen in AI demo from TechEd2014, that App health & Diagnostic part isn't working for azure web sites yet...

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

confirmed that if you deployed your app to an azure website that you will miss seeing some data in the Application Insights blade.  the 2 data flows that won't work specifically include 1) the runtime instrumentation agent - this acts like a profiler and automatically discovers your code dependencies like calls to SQL, another HTTP endpoint, Azure storage account or azure blob and 2) Windows systems performance counters.

1) is something that is very close to being released as an Azure website extension http://www.siteextensions.net/ and will depend on the .12 Application Insight SDK (not released yet)
2) is something that we are still working on an ETA for

Other data visible in the application insights blade should already be working on an azure website. If you don't see your data make sure you are looking at the right application insights resource and double check the instrumentation key.  Also make sure you have manually added the client side instrumentation script which isn't added by default when we add application insights to an existing project (ie. not a new project).